# Azure Function App - private assembly gets cached - updating file has no effect

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, azure-functions

I created a simple function triggered by Event Hubs. Created a POCO library with a couple simple classes. Uploaded the library assembly to the function/bin folder. Created a console test app that references the library and writes one of the objects defined in the library to event hubs.

Everything works. Dance around for joy and reward self with cookie. Functions are going to save me $3,000 a year in VM fees.Time to get serious. I make updates to the class that I'm posting to event hubs to simulate the actual data I'll be posting IRL. I adjust the version in the assembly info, build and upload the updated assembly to the /bin folder.

Next I adjust my Azure function to access a new property on the class. Just simple stuff - outputting to the log. It compiles. At runtime I get an error saying the backing function (get_MyProp) doesn't exist in the assembly. Huh? Then why did it compile?

I tested that the compiler is using the right assembly by trying to access a property that was on the class in version 1, but removed in version 2. This generates a compiler error as expected.

So long story short, it seems to be correctly using the recently uploaded assembly at compile time, but using a cached version of the assembly at runtime. I've tried stopping and starting the app service and a few other things to no avail.

Any ideas how I can remove the first uploaded version of the assembly from the runtime cache?

Here is the sample function:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "AzureFunctionTest4.dll"

using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using AzureFunctionTest;

public static void Run(string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    //log.Info($"Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {myEventHubMessage}");

    DatagramMetadata message = null;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myEventHubMessage))
        message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatagramMetadata>(myEventHubMessage);

    if(message != null) 
    {
        log.Info($"Setting Sample: {message.NewProperty}");
    }
}
```

Here is the sample POCO:

```
public sealed class DatagramMetadata
{
    public string MyProp
    {
        get
        {
            return Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;
        }
    }
    public DateTime Observed { get; set; }
    public string EndpointIPAddress { get; set; }
    public int EndpointPort { get; set; }
    public string DeviceIPAddress { get; set; }
    public int DevicePort { get; set; }
    public string Datagram { get; set; }
    public string NewProperty { get; set; } // <--- new property
}
```

Before uploading the assembly with the "NewProperty" on the datagram class, I get this error as expected:

> error CS1061: 'DatagramMetadata' does not contain a definition for
>   'NewProperty' and no extension method 'NewProperty' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'DatagramMetadata' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

After uploading:

> Compilation succeeded.

When running:

> 2016-11-18T22:27:09.720 Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.EventHubTriggerCSharp1. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. EventHubTriggerCSharp1: Method not
>   found: 'System.String
>   AzureFunctionTest.DatagramMetadata.get_NewProperty()'.

Assembly version uploaded and used at compile time is 8.9.10.11 Assembly used at runtime is 6.0.6166.5285.

Thanks in advance for anyone who offers ideas.

Comment: Thank you to the folks who fixed the tags to make them more relevant.

Comment: Hey Mark, definitely a strange issue as this should work as expected, so let's dig in to see what's going on... I want to confirm one thing, when you say you changed the assembly version in AssemblyInfo, I want to make sure you're referring to the AssemblyVersionAttribute, and not AssemblyFileVersion (sorry if it seems basic, but it's a common issue). Could you share your function app name either directly or indirectly as described here :https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: Hi Fabio, I changed both:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("8.9.10.11")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("8.9.10.11")]
I'll check the link you provided and get back to you in a minute.

Comment: The app is m2mudpgateway.azurewebsites.net. 
The function name is EventHubTriggerCSharp1 (very clever, I know)

Comment: Before I started troubleshooting this, I used the star in my assembly version like this [assembly: AssemblyVersion("8.9.*")] so I don't have to mess with it. I started setting it explicitly as part of the troubleshooting process.

Comment: I'll try to setup a repro for this, but this seems strange as a site restart should absolutely drop all loaded assemblies. Any chance you can restart your site in process explorer in Kudu? Also, can you output/log your the assembly version by using typeof(DatagramMetadata).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString()?

Comment: Yes, I can output the assembly version. That's how I figured out that the runtime version was different than the compile version. I'll try restarting in Kudo.

log.Info($"Assembly: {message.GetType().Assembly.FullName}");

Comment: That's what is strange as the runtime does not cache that information anywhere. Did you have any other functions deployed or other copies of that assembly in different directories? Have you tried killing the process from Kudu?

Comment: Killing the process in Kudo worked. The assembly version at runtime is now correct..

Comment: I did upload the same assembly in another Function App. I created one with Consumption pricing and when I encountered problems with the assembly not updating, I created a Standard Small service plan. Stopping and starting either one from the Azure portal didn't solve the problem.

Comment: More info. I can see that the process ID changes in the Kudo process explorer when I restart the app service from the Azure portal, but changes to the assembly and associated config file don't take effect unless I kill the process from Kudo.

Comment: So, to confirm, the problem was resolved with a Kudu restart, but you can easily repro, correct? Could you open an issue at https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script with details so we can further investigate?

Comment: Yeah, I can reproduce at will. I'll open an issue at GitHub. Thanks for the help so far.